# Widget not getting displayed in pyqt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I am new to python and even newer to PyQt. My button widget is not getting displayed in the window. I am sure I have made a silly mistake down here.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPushButton, QApplication

class Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Buttons")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 500, 500)
        self.show()
        self.main()

    def main(self):
        button = QPushButton('Quit', self)
        button.clicked.connect(QApplication.instance().quit)
        button.resize(button.sizeHint())
        button.move(150, 150)
        self.show()

def run():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
run()
```

Help would be apriciated.

Answer (score 0):

In `def main(self):` you call `show()` on `self`. It should be `button.show()` instead.

Comment: That fixed the problem. Thanks a lot.